# How to find visible span html text contains certain text in jQuery

Tags: jquery

Just wandering, will be possible to find all `visible span html text` that contains certain text in `jQuery`?

I have the following code:

```
<div id="test">
  <span style="display:none;">one</span>
  <span style="display:inline;">two</span>
  <span style="display:inline;">three</span>
  <span style="display:none;">four</span>
  <span style="display:inline;">five</span>
</div>
```

Anyway I can use `jQuery` to find out whether any `visible span contain text` "two"?

Answer (score 0):

You can use`(:visible)`

```
var visiblespans = $('span:visible');

visiblespans.each(function(){
    if($.trim(this.text()) == 'two') {
        console.log(this.text());
    }
});
```

https://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/

Answer (score 0):

You could use `#test > span:visible` selector to get the visible `span` elements, and then `$(this).text()` to get their inner Text or `$(this).html()` for inner HTML.

```js
$("#test > span:visible").each(function() {
  console.log("Text:" + $(this).text());
  console.log("HTML:" + $(this).html());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="test">
  <span style="display:none;">one</span>
  <span style="display:inline;">two</span>
  <span style="display:inline;">three</span>
  <span style="display:none;">four</span>
  <span style="display:inline;">five</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. use [:visible](https://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/) selector

   > Description: Selects all elements that are visible.
2. use [:contains](https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) selector

   > Description: Select all elements that contain the specified text.

```js
var arr = $('#test').find('span:visible:contains(two)').map(function(){

return $(this).text()
}).get()

console.log(arr)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="test">
<span style="display:none;">one</span>
<span style="display:inline;">two</span>
<span style="display:inline;">three</span>
<span style="display:none;">four</span>
<span style="display:inline;">five</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go with a solution https://jsfiddle.net/zk0Lvkmt/

```js
$('#test').find('span').each(function(){
  if($(this).is(':visible')){
    console.log($(this).text());
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="test">
  <span style="display:none;">one</span>
  <span style="display:inline;">two</span>
  <span style="display:inline;">three</span>
  <span style="display:none;">four</span>
  <span style="display:inline;">five</span>
</div>
```

Only `visible span text` will be `console.log`

Loop through all the span using `jQuery each` method & check whether the span is visible or not using `$(this).is(':visible');`

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

you can use following code for accessing all visible span

```
$(function(){
  $.each($('span:visible'),function(ind,val){
    console.log(val);
    $(".visibleText").append(val);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could make use of the jquery filter method to filter only the required elements.
so, 
You could do,

```
$('#test > span').filter(function(){
 return ($(this).text() === 'two') && ($(this).is(':visible'))
})
```

This will return all the elements which have the text **'two'** and **is visible**